# Android WebView doesn't redraw css changes made

Tags: android, css, webview, webkit, android-webview

I am working on a WebView to display a site that I have no control over the HTML/CSS. The page when clicking on a element will open a Modal window and play a video. The problem is the Modal doesn't show up when the css on it is changed to include the "show" tag. If I rotate the device then the WebView will rerender and show the modal properly, but only on orientation change.

Is there any other way around this other then forcing the user to change orientation to make the WebView rerender dynamic CSS changes like showing a Modal popup?